# Почему у Entity указывается implements Serializable?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, сериализация, entity

Обратил внимание, что по в JPA есть требования к составному ключу и embedded-class, которое гласит, что для них необходимо имплементировать маркерный интерфейс Serializable ([Java Persistence API - 2.4)](https://github.com/javaee/jpa-spec/blob/master/jsr338-MR/JavaPersistence.pdf). Почему основной Entity-класс не обязательно должен реализовывать Serializable? И почему тогда составной ключ и embedded-class должны этому соотвествовать ?